# Why different command scripts are used for the same command when run as a normal user and when run as a root user?

Tags: users, root, command

I see the script location for the command `date` for a normal user, it shows

```
which date
/bin/date
```

But when I run the same command from root it shows the output `/usr/bin/date`. Why so ?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Which *nix variant - or which GNU/Linux distribution - are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If `which date` produces different results for `root` and another user, then it's likely that they have different values for `PATH`.  The normal user has `/bin` earlier than `/usr/bin` (or without `/usr/bin` at all) and `root` has `/usr/bin/` before `/bin` (or without `/bin` at all).

You can verify this by running:

```
echo ${PATH}
```

as both `root` and the non-root user.

The `PATH` variable is a colon-delimited list of directories in which the shell looks for commands when the absolute path isn't provided.  The shell will search those directories, left to right, in the order that they're listed.  If the shell finds a command in a directory, then it executes it.  The `which` command does a similar walk and reports the first match that it finds.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the `$PATH` variable of the user you are currently logged in. If the script is on more than one directories the first found is used, in this case `$PATH` of root should be something like

```
PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:...
```

and for the user it should be something like

```
 PATH="/bin...
```